# How to Create ViewFields in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, workflow, viewfields

I have two different lists:

List1 contains 4 Columns.

List2 contains 4 Columns. 
(List1 columns and List2 columns are same)

Lets say, List1 has four items stored. Now, I want List2 to have the same items which List1 has. How can I do it?

How to create ViewFields for List2?
Is a workflow required?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this easily with a designer workflow. Create a designer workflow with a "Create List Item" action. Specify the list where new item has to be created and the mapping of the columns.
The steps are same for SharePoint 2013 workflow as well.
http://blogs.salmanghani.info/create-item-workflow-sharepoint-designer-2010/